# "Password type input with autocomplete enabled" an Acunext Audit warning, How to resolve it

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

We had Acunext Audit for our website and they said "Password type input with autocomplete enabled" is an informational warning.

How can we resolve it, is it necessary?

My site is in asp.net 2.0 hosted on IIS 7

Comment: and how is this related to php?

Comment: if they have any code at client side

Comment: Is it necessary? Depends on your situation. Allowing the autocomplete on a password field could be a big security risk if a machine were shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the type="password" and autocomplete="off"

Comment: does it equivlent to AutoCompleteType= None in aspx , i don't find AutoComplete attribute in aspx

Comment: I suppose you can try that. I'm more of an MVC person. I'd inspect the element in Firebug / Chrome debug tools after it gets rendered